# Modify Array formatting in php

Tags: php, arrays

I want to change array formatting in php but i'm getting error.

**I want output like this**

```
    [
      ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses', 'Profit'],
      ['2014', 1000, 400, 200],
      ['2015', 1170, 460, 250],
      ['2016', 660, 1120, 300],
      ['2017', 1030, 540, 350]
    ]
```

**php code**

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT `year`, `sales`,`expenses`,`profit` 
              FROM chart 
              ORDER BY `year` ASC");

$data = array('Year','Sales','Expenses','Profit');

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
   $data[] = array($row['year'], $row['sales'], $row['expenses'], 
   $row['profit']);
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

**Output**

```
["Year","Sales","Expenses","Profit",
["2012","20000","15000","5000"],
["2013","30000","18000","12000"],
["2014","100000","60000","40000"],
["2015","250000","150000","100000"],
["2016","15000","12000","3000"]
]
```

Comment: `$data = array(array('Year','Sales','Expenses','Profit'));`

Comment: `mysql_` functions are deprecated!

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
$data = array('Year','Sales','Expenses','Profit');
```

To

```
$data[] = array('Year','Sales','Expenses','Profit');
```